# Wiring question

Tags: batteries, wiring

I would like to take a 96 LED Infrared light (12v 2 amp) and cut the cord and add a battery wiring harness. Can I just add two 9v battery wiring harnesses to it? I'm pretty confident that I could add one 9v harness to a 48 LED light. Is there a different battery option or an inline option that would serve my needs better? Thanks!

Comment: a standard 9V battery running at 2 amps is going to discharge in like 5 minutes or less.

Answer (score 3):

A typical 9V battery has around 950 mAh capacity, as well as a high ESR, equivalent series resistance. It is intended for low current long time purposes. A 2 amp draw, probably 1.5 Amps with 9 Volts, will cause a large voltage drop on the battery because of the high ESR, and will quickly drain it. When two in parallel won't last much longer.

Comment: What size (and how many) batteries would be more appropriate? Ideally, I would like to get 8 hours of life out it.

Comment: What's a nAmp? Is there a standard size battery that could be used?

Comment: @tronicmoron I updated my comment.

Comment: Wow...that's just not feasible. How unfortunate. The site says to refrain from saying thank you...but, Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, that's 16 Amp Hours, 12 Volts. It's 168 Watt Hours. Like golf cart,  or emergency lighting SLA battery. Not quite yet a car battery. The size of a brick.

Comment: If I dropped the working time to 4 hours...what size then?

Comment: @tronicmoron 2A * 4h = 8hA at 12V That's a small SLA emergency lighting battery. Like 20~30 bucks at home depot brand new.

Comment: @tronicmoron hell, some usb or 12V power banks can do 8aH but they are physically big bulky

Answer (score 1):

A common alkaline D-cell has a capacity of 12000 to 18000 mAh. Eight D-cells would total 12V, and theoretically, 12000 mAh would last 6 hours. But in the Real World, you would be lucky to get 4 hours out of eight D cells.

Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_battery#Dimensions_and_capacity

Comment: Real world, as the Voltage drops, the current draw would drop, so it's really like 6~7 hours until the light isn't bright.

Answer (score 0):

I think a 9V LiPo battery would be better for something like this if you want to keep the form factor the same. Rechargeable batteries are better suited for projects with a relatively high current draw; like motors on an RC car for example. You'd have to find one that's rated at 2000mAh discharge though.